Casted pointer does not get desired properties and methods for abstract parent class
I have a program where I instantiated an abstract parent class and cast a pointer of a child class (C-style type cast) to one of the parent class. When I looked up properties and called functions, for some it worked, for others it returned the property of the parent class and does not call any function (it called the vitrual void funcName() = 0).
Please ignore any potential memory leaks, the code is guaranteed to run in an isolated sandbox that detroys itself as soon as the program terminates.
A minimal reproducable example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
using std::string, std::cin, std::cout, std::vector, std::deque, std::endl;

typedef long long ll;
ll n, m, k, nExec;
namespace op {
    const ll slack = 0, move = 1, swap = 2, mirror = 3, replace = 4, activate = 5, trigger = 6;
}

class operation {
public:
    ll time, bot;
    ll type = -1;
    virtual void negate() = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
class slack:public operation{
public:
    ll type = op::slack;
    virtual void print() override {if(nExec == k) exit(0);cout << "Robot " << bot << " slacks off." << endl;}
    virtual void negate() override {}
    virtual void execute() override {
        if(nExec == k) exit(0);
        nExec++;
    }
};

int main() {
    // freopen("fix.in", "r", stdin);
    // freopen("fix.out", "w", stdout);
    k = 998244353;
    operation* op = new slack;
    cout << op->type << endl;
    op->print();
    return 0;
}

Outputs:
-1
Robot 0 slacks off.

In specific, execute (and sometimes print) worked, but type does not work at all (negate is untested).
Access full code here.

Also, the program is guaranteed to terminate within 1 second.

Using typedefs here, should work properly with pointers and refrences.

Typedefs work differently than plain text replacement, which is the case for a #define. Moreover, expect the environment to be consistent and expect the code to only run once. Please disregard such concerns in answers.

please show a [mre]. Note that ll type = op::slack; declares a new variable and is unrelated to operation::type

operation::type, slack::type are two distinct and independent member variables, they are not "virtual"

@jett8998 you are right that there are relevant differences between #defines and typedef/using. However - IMHO using the plain types (or fixed size types like int64_t) is prefered.

Thanks all. @Quimby What should I do if I'm to have slack::type remain op::slack even when I'm refrencing it from an operator* (it is instantiated as a slack)?

And I'd also like to know why in the full code, print does not work while execute does.

"Please ignore any potential memory leaks" Simpler to just fix the code. it is shorter than that line, and also avoid comment about that (even if asked to ignore that issue).

@jett8998 Ok goot. Perhaps you could remove the massive amount of unused variables too? Can you also clarify what you mean by "execute (and sometimes print) worked, but type does not work at all"? I think it looks like it's doing the expected

ll type = op::slack; should be removed, use proper constructor to initialize operation::type to op::slack for slack.

To be specific, execute called the right function in all contexts, print only called the right function in main and type always referenced to the one in the base class. By the "right" function, I mean the function in the child class.

print is only called in main? Where is it not working?

Output looks correct to me. Where do you think it is not working (and why?).

There should be no need to use a C-style cast for a pointer of a child class to a pointer a parent class.

If you want type to behave polymorphically, make it a virtual function, like virtual ll getType() const = 0; (in operation, and override appropriately in slack). As written, an object of type slack has two distinct independent data members, one named type (or slack::type), the other named operation::type. When accessed via operation* pointer, op->type refers to operation::type. There ain't no such thing as a virtual data member; only member functions can be virtual.

Also, turn on your compiler warnings.  Fix those compiler warnings.  That'll eliminate dozens of bugs.

There are no casts in this code, "down" or otherwise. There is an implicit conversion from pointer-to-derived-type  to pointer-to-base-type. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.
